# Launch Bootstrap Carousel On Button Click

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am creating project in codeigniter
There is a facility to upload multiple images
I simply wants to display images in bootstrap carousel when show button is clicked or if somebody have any other idea to display the images when show image is clicked, I will be very thankful to them
Thank You Very Much

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i have changed the question, now please can u give ,me some solutions

Comment: It is still unclear to me. Do you want to preview images on upload page or something else? Also, you have to show existing code and let us know what [and where] error occurs.